# A cv with or without passport photo while applying for postdoc

Tags: mathematics, job-search, postdocs

I am a Ph.D student from mathematics background and about to submit my thesis in a month or two. I am thinking to apply for postdoc position. Shall I send my normal cv or the one bearing my photo? Thanks for the help and suggestions.

Comment: This is culture dependent.  In what country will you be applying?